# all menus, icons ,programs & folders (desktop or program menu) is invisible & not opening in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, gnome-terminal, directory, desktop-icons, menu-bar

UBUNTU 20.04 issue : all the icons & folders (desktop or program menu) is invisible & not opening (including terminal), however pointing the cursor makes them identifiable.This happened after running an update command on terminal. How can the problem be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a custom theme installed? Maybe the update broke it.

Go to a virtual console with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>, and log in there by typing your username and then sudo password when prompted for it.

Issue the following command to reset to the default Ubuntu theme:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme Yaru
```

Return to the graphical session with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.

Maybe also try logging out + logging back in.

Comment: Dear Sir, I performed aforementioned prompt in virtual console &  it showed : 'gsetting' not found.  Try  sudo apt install (deb name).

Comment: @ARITRA To me it looks like you might have missed an `s` from the end of it? It's `gsettings`, with an `s` at the end.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the mistakes@Levente. Now the desktop looks :: icons(only names are showing) are floating  on blue background. Even after restarting PC, issue remained same.

Comment: @ARITRA So, if you do `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme`, then it prints `Yaru`? Or something else? Also, what gnome-shell extesions have you installed? Maybe one of them got broken? You can list your extensions with `gsettings get org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions`

Comment: Dear Levente, it prints 'Adwaita' ( not 'Yaru'). And the second command returns with:  @as [].

Comment: I have run out of ideas. But I have updated my answer, so your question is again visible on the frontpage list; let's hope someone with fresh ideas sees it and suggests something new.

Comment: `apt list --installed | grep theme` <--- It would be amazing if you could share with us somehow the value that this command prints. Or, at least tell whether you see things like `yaru-theme`-something in that list. Also if yes, then what those are?

Comment: Yup,it returns with a whopping list : adium-theme, adwaita-icon-theme,gnome-themes, Plymouth-theme ,  xcursor theme along with yaru-theme(yaru-theme-gnome-shell/focal-updates,  yaru-theme-icon/focal-updates, yaru-theme-icon/focal-updates)

Comment: Ooops, now I see you have expanded your installed theme list. `yaru-theme-gtk` seems to be missing. (I do have `yaru-theme-gtk`) I think that's what you need, and that's why trying to set the gtk-theme to Yaru did not work as intended.

Comment: Thanks  for getting the problem. What can be done right now(if any) to restore default slick theme of Yaru, removing all the expanded themes at once? Please write down appropriate   commands  for virtual console.

Comment: To be precise, I have 4 items: `yaru-theme-gnome-shell`, `yaru-theme-gtk`, `yaru-theme-icon`, and `yaru-theme-sound`, so that's normal to have all these, one shouldn't remove any of it, I believe.

Comment: This is just an idea: `sudo apt install yaru-theme-gtk` But I must say, I have never tried this command, and I don't have any experience if it has any side-effect or anything. So if you decide to try it out, then that's up to you. You can run a "simulated variant" of this command first, to see how it would go: `sudo apt install yaru-theme-gtk -s` (see the `-s` at the end). This will not change anything, just show you how it would go. If the command output looks good, then you could try without the `-s`; then it would run for real.

Comment: If that succeeds, then you would need to run the `gsettings set ... ` command that's above in my original answer.

Comment: Thanks a ton, @Levente. I tried with command : "sudo apt -- fix-broken installed " & problems got solved. Thanks again for the guidance.